# Why I cannot redirect form authenticated method Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

In `AuthenticatesUsers` trait I found this code

`if (method_exists($this, 'authenticated')) {
  return $this->authenticated($request, Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->user());
 }`

So, I defined the authenticated method in `AuthController`

```
protected function authenticated($user)
{

  if ($user->activated == 0) {
     return redirect("login")->with("error", "errorMsg") ;
  }
  else {
     return redirect("/") ;
  }
}
```

And there happen nothing just, I got just white page

Comment: The function appears to take both a $request object and a $user one.

Comment: @JoelHinz And do you mean I have to return the $request object?

Comment: @JoelHinz Oh yeah, thank you have solved it.